# Protractor E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199

Tags: protractor, gulp-protractor

when i run gulp to start protractor i got this error

E/launcher - unknown error: cannot parse capability: proxy
from unknown error: proxyType is 'manual' but no manual proxy capabilities were found
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299
x86_64)

protractor version 5.1.1

gulpfile

```
ar gulp = require('gulp');
var path = require('path');
var child_process = require('child_process');

var requireDir = require('require-dir');
requireDir('./config/gulp/tasks');

var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var open = require('gulp-open');



gulp.task('default', [
    //'complete'
    'protractor-test'
]);



function getBinary(packageName, binaryLocation) {
    var pkgPath = require.resolve(packageName);
    return path.resolve(path.join(path.dirname(pkgPath), '..', binaryLocation));
}

gulp.task('protractor-install', function(done) {
    var binary = getBinary('webdriver-manager', '../bin/webdriver-manager');
    child_process.spawn('node', [binary, 'update --versions.chrome 2.29'], {
        stdio: 'inherit'
    }).once('close', function() {
        done();
    });
});

gulp.task('protractor-start', function(done) {
    var binary = getBinary('protractor', 'bin/protractor');
    child_process.spawn('node', [binary, 'protractor.conf.js'], {
        stdio: 'inherit'
    }).once('close', function() {
        gulp.src('protractor-results/report.html')
            .pipe(open({ app: 'chrome' }));
        done();
    });
});

gulp.task('t', function() {
    runSequence('start-server',
        'start-proxy',
        'protractor-start',
        'stop-servers');
});

gulp.task('debug-proxy', function(done) {
    child_process.spawn('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', ['--proxy-server=http=localhost:8080', '--user-data-dir=C:\\tmp', 'http://localhost:49852'], {
        stdio: 'inherit'
    }).once('close', function() {
        done();
    });
});
```

and the config of protractor

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            prefs: {
                'credentials_enable_service': false,
                'profile': {
                    'password_manager_enabled': false
                }
            }
        },
        'proxy': {
            'proxyType': 'manual',
            'httpsProxy': 'localhost:3000'
        }
    },
    framework: 'jasmine',

    specs: [
        'Tests/Common/common-e2e-spec.js',
        // 'Tests/S4B/skype4-business-e2e-spec.js',
        // 'Tests/CM/client-management-e2e-spec.js',
        //  'Tests/MC/manage-compute-e2e-spec.js'

    ],

    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    baseUrl: 'https://localhost:44300',
    beforeLaunch: function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            screenshotreporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
        });
    },
    onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(screenshotreporter);
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(xmlreporter1);
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(xmlreporter2);
    },
    afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            screenshotreporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
        });
    },

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        //1 minute timeout
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
        showTiming: true,
        print: function() {}
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run gulp *without* sudo!!!